# Timer class based, Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried to read similar solutions for this problem and none of it able to solve my problem. From the console error, it stated that I have an error in this line

```
this.setState({ submitted: true, finalScore });
```

I am currently making a quiz app using ReactJS where it has a timer. Which, once the timer reaches to 0 - It will automatically submit the answer.

this is my **render**

```
  render() {
    const { questionBank, submitted, finalScore, minute, second } = this.state;


    return (
      <Box>
        <h2>Pop Quiz!</h2>
        <h3>Time remaining: {minute}:{second< 10 ? `0${ second }` : second}</h3>
        { minute === 0 && second === 0
            ? this.handleSubmit() : <div>{!submitted &&
          questionBank.length > 0 &&
          questionBank.map(
            ({ question, answers, correct, questionId }, index) => (
              <QuestionBox
                key={questionId}
                index={index + 1}
                question={question}
                options={answers}
                selected={(answer) =>
                  this.computeAnswer(answer, correct, questionId)
                }
              />
            )
          )}
              {!submitted && (
                  <Box align="end">
                    <Button
                        primary
                        label="Submit"
                        onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}
                    />
                  </Box>
              )}

              {submitted && <Result score={finalScore} playAgain={this.playAgain} />}

        </div>
        }
      </Box>
    );
  }
```

this is my **timer**

```
timer = () => {
    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      const { second, minute } = this.state

      if (second > 0) {
        this.setState(({ second }) => ({
          second: second - 1
        }))
      }
      if (second === 0) {
        if (minute === 0) {
          clearInterval(this.myInterval)
        } else {
          this.setState(({ minute }) => ({
            minute: minute - 1,
            second: 59
          }))
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.getQuestions();
    this.timer();

  }
```

and this is **handleSubmit**

```
handleSubmit() {
    const {
      correctQuestionAnswered,
      questionBank: { length },
    } = this.state;

    const { db } = this.props;

    const finalScore = ((correctQuestionAnswered / length) * 100).toFixed(2);
    const currentdate = new Date();
    const dateTime =
      currentdate.getDate() +
      "/" +
      (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) +
      "/" +
      currentdate.getFullYear() +
      " @ " +
      currentdate.getHours() +
      ":" +
      currentdate.getMinutes() +
      ":" +
      currentdate.getSeconds();

    db.put({
      _id: new Date().toJSON(),
      submit_datetime: dateTime,
      score: finalScore,
    });

    this.setState({ submitted: true, finalScore }); // <--- This is the line that I get an error
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
```

Where did I go wrong that gives me this result? I am still fairly new in reactJS

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state
```

**//Edit:**
After tweaking some more, I managed somehow fixed it by moving the submitHandler to the timer when it reaches 00:00 and erase the `this.forceUpdate()` within submitHandler. However, I am still not entirely sure why the previous design doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you are calling setState in your `render` method, which is not allowed in React.

This line of code in your `render` method is illegally causing the setState to be called:

```
{ minute === 0 && second === 0
        ? this.handleSubmit()
```

You should move this state check into a `componentDidUpdate()` method in your component's class. In short, `componentDidUpdate()` is called whenever the props or state of your component changes (in other words, whenever your component renders). [Learn about componentDidUpdate() here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Here you should check the `minute` and `second` state, and call the handleSubmit() method accordingly:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.state.minute === 0 && this.state.second === 0) {
        this.handleSubmit()
    }
}
```

And remove the `minute === 0 && second === 0` ternary from the render method.

If you have any problems while implementing my solution, please let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go over your code in great detail since you fixed the issue, but I believe it is because you called your state inside the render() method. Each time there is a change (for you always, since you are counting down) your state is stuck in an infinite loop. it should be mentioned in the constructor() or use a tool like redux.

edit: beat to the punch and much more elegantly...